# Magento Category/Product view no Page numbering

Tags: php, magento

I am using this code to display products on specific pages in Magento:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

This works great. The only problem I have is that there is no page numbering if there are more products than a user can't navigate to the next page.

Does somebody have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: means you are not getting complete pagination toolbar on that page?

Comment: there isn't any pagination toolbar displayed on the page

Comment: open the file `app\design\frontend\THEME\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml` you can get idea from there to display toolbar

Comment: can't find any code that I can implement in my code to display the pagination toolbar. I want an extra piece of code that will display the page numbers and the navigation to these numbers.